# Why doesn't MySQL use an index for "in query" subqueries?

Tags: mysql

If I run a simple in query it completes very quickly:

```
explain select * from my_data where id in (132730151);
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_data | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

If I run essentially the same query with a subquery it never seems to complete:

```
explain select * from my_data where id in (select my_data_id from my_other_data where id = 46855459);
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | type  | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref   | rows      | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | my_data       | ALL   | NULL                     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | 132862517 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | my_other_data | const | PRIMARY,my_data_id_index | PRIMARY | 4       | const |         1 |             |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------+--------------------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

It seems like MySQL is going through every row for this case.  Why doesn't mysql use the primary index on id for the second case?

My example is a bit contrived.  I'm actually using mysqldump to export a range of data and this is the simplest case.  Since I'm using mysqldump I can't convert this into a join since I only have access to the where clause.

Comment: Because the MySQL query optimizer sucks.

Comment: What is the ancient mysql version are you using?

Comment: What about if you make it a join instead of using `WHERE IN`?

Comment: @Mr. Llama: normally mysql optimizes both `IN` and correspondingly rewritten `INNER JOIN` in a similar way.

Comment: @ActiveApathy: What if you run `ANALYZE` and `OPTIMIZE` on both tables?

Comment: @Mr.Llama Read the last paragraph of the question for why he can't use a JOIN.

Comment: @zerkms I've seen many cases where the `IN (SELECT...)` query was "optimized" by scanning the full outer table and then searching for the ID in the index of the inner table.

Comment: @zerkms I'm using version=5.5.34-32.0-log.

Comment: @ActiveApathy: what about `ANALYZE` and `OPTIMIZE` then?

Comment: @Barmar: that's because `INNER JOIN` and `IN(subquery)` are transformed to the similar plan and that allows optimizer to change the order. And in most cases it's either really more performant or is caused by obsolete statistics.